# Best way for uploading binary Application Loader or Xcode organizer

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, xcodebuild, application-loader

I want to know best way for uploading binary to itunestore. Is it through Application loader or using Xcode organizer archive build, validate and submit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>You don't use Application Loader in Xcode 4 anymore. You can only upload through the Xcode Organiser...</strike>

As zekel mentions below, you can still use Application Loader to submit your IPA files. The Xcode Organiser method is useful if you are building the app yourself and want to validate and submit from one place. Application Loader method is useful if you have the IPA signed to the correct certificates installed on your system.

After using both methods, Application Loader gives you more indication of progress status which is useful if you are on a slow connection.

Comment: Reason of not using Application Loader as far in knowledge it work same at the end.both are use for uploading binary.

Comment: I use Organizer, but am wondering why Application Loader is included if it is deprecated.

Comment: Well in Organiser you can only submit applications which you've compiled and archived. If a software shop has provided the IPA signed with your certificates, you may want to submit it yourself or something. I think it's just another tool included so you don't necessarily have to open Xcode. Presumably it will be removed or become unsupported sometime in the future.

Comment: If you want to upload an IPA file directly (perhaps one built via the `xcodebuild` command) you still will want to use Application Loader.

Answer (score 10):

There are significant differences which I've tried to list below (as of Xcode 6.3.2 - Jun 2015):

**Xcode Organiser**

- The application to submit must be selected from the list of your locally archived apps (you cannot browse to a specfic file)
- Gives option to 'Validate' your app before submitting
- At validate/submission time will download/sync all the provisioning profiles associated with the selected Apple developer account and re-sign/re-embed the application with the appropriate one (it does indicate which one's get selected but you cannot override this)
- Gives option to automatically upload the debugging symbols that are included in the archived application
- NO upload progress
- (Gives the option to Export to an *.ipa which could be used with Application Loader)

**Application Loader**

- Requires you browse to an *.ipa file for its input
- No option to Validate before submitting
- Uses the provisioning profile that is already embedded in the *.ipa file
- NO way to upload debugging symbols
- Gives upload progress

Answer (score 3):

A sole developer or small team might just submit directly from Xcode, especially for a smaller project.  But for a larger team, more complex project, or an automated build system, submitting from the Application Loader is easier.

It's a matter of workflow more than anything else.

Answer (score 1):

I mostly use Application Loader it is best because:

It just requires you browse to an `.ipa` file.

We need not to worry about the provisioning profile that is already embedded in the `.ipa` file.

NO way to upload debugging symbols

We need not to Validate before submitting.

We can see the progress bar where and what is the status of app uploading.