# How to deploy Xamarin iOS App with .dSYM file

Tags: ios, xamarin

I've been looking at Microsoft's docs for deploying Xamarin iOS apps to the app store:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/index?tabs=windows

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/ipa-support?tabs=windows

We are currently building in Ad-Hoc and generating an .ipa file which we then upload to the app store via Application Loader. I managed to get the .dSYM folder to generate if I set the Project Properties -> Build -> Advanced -> Debugging Information to "Full" in Visual Studio.

Is there a better way to upload the .ipa, or a way to upload the .dSYM to iTunes Connect? As I read that Apple will automatically symbolicate any crash logs for you if the symbols were uploaded with the app?

Also, does setting the Debugging Information to "Full" change the actual .ipa in any way, or does it just generate the extra .dSYM file? Since setting it to "Full" I manually deployed the .ipa to our test device and one the libraries we use is now throwing an Object Reference exception.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a better way to upload the .ipa?

In my knowledge, there are two ways to upload .ipa file to iTunes Connect. One is `XCode` and the other is `Application Loader`.

> or a way to upload the .dSYM to iTunes Connect? As I read that Apple
>   will automatically symbolicate any crash logs for you if the symbols
>   were uploaded with the app?

***"you will be given the option of including the dSYM file when uploading your archive to iTunes Connect. In the submission dialog, check “Include app symbols for your application…*** `DSYM` files store the debug symbols for your app, it should exist at the machine that compiled the app binary. Read the answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656391/whats-the-dsym-and-how-to-use-it-ios-sdk) would help you understand what is a DSYM file better.

Here is the document about [Understanding and Analyzing Application Crash Reports](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html).

> or does it just generate the extra .dSYM file?

I don't think so, there is only a DSYM file after you compiled the app binary.

> Since setting it to "Full" I manually deployed the .ipa to our test
>   device and one the libraries we use is now throwing an Object
>   Reference exception.

What is the Object Reference exception? Any stackTrace?

Comment: So that link to Apple's technical notes states: "you will be given the option of including the dSYM file when uploading your archive to iTunes Connect. In the submission dialog, check “Include app symbols for your application…”." but I didn't see that option in Application Loader at least.

Comment: I think the object reference exception is to do with how I manually put the .ipa on the device somehow since it runs fine in debug and when getting the app from TestFlight, but I'm not too concerned about this part.

Comment: @Kiblinix The option exist in the XCode.

Comment: @Kiblinix See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30713186/10539446), it listed that Application Loader has no way to upload debugging symbols.

Comment: Do I have to build the solution in XCode for that? Or can I build in VS and then transfer whatever file over to the Mac?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is an archive in XCode after you build the file in VS. I would do some research and update you later. You can also use [appcenter](https://appcenter.ms/apps) to track the crashes.